# How to Prevent an Alert Dialog Getting Closed by Back Button

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I have an alert dialog like this:

```
    AlertDialog.Builder oyunaBaslaDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    oyunaBaslaDialog.setMessage("A Takımı");
    oyunaBaslaDialog.setNeutralButton("Başla!",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    oyunOyna();
                }
            });
    oyunaBaslaDialog.show();
```

This dialog is shown in onCreate method. And I want it just to be closed by the button on it. But Hardware Back Button can also close this dialog without dialog's action performed.

I dont want the back button close this dialog, what can i do?

Answer (score 58):

Use [Dialog.setCancelable()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29):

> Sets whether this dialog is cancelable with the BACK key.

In your code this would be:

```
oyunaBaslaDialog.setCancelable(false);
```

Comment: But what if you simply want to decide whether or not the back key closes the dialog based on certain conditions?

Comment: If your dialog is inside DialogFragment you will need to call setCancelable(false) for the DialogFragment otherwise Back will close the fragment. Link to the docs: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#setCancelable%28boolean%29

Answer (score 10):

Implement setOnKeyListener and catch the KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK.
If you return true in this method, dialog will not close.

Comment: This way you can actually do what ever you want when user presses back button on Dialog.

Comment: This was the only usefull solution for me because I wanted to add an action to the back button.

Answer (score 0):

there is a method called,
`bulder.setCancelable(`).by default this cancelable set '**true**'.override it with,

```
bulder.setCancelable(false)
```