# How do I disable the Android back button during a popup?

Tags: android, popup, back-button

I know how to disable the back button, but not during a popup.

```
syncb=(Button) findViewById(R.id.SyncB);
syncb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() 
    {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(Scouting.this);
            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.popup);
            dialog.setTitle("Popups ftw");
            dialog.setCancelable(true);
            //I think I'd put the code here...
            Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.closePopup);
            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }    
            });
            dialog.show();
        }
    });
```

I've tried everything from

```
@Override public void dialog.onBackPressed() { }
```

to

```
@Override dialog.onBackPressed({});
```

and I can't find anything that works.

Edit:
Usually, it's

```
@Override public void onBackPressed(){}
```

and it's usually in the main class(not 'nested') but since I'm dug in a little...I'm not figuring it out(trying to, but not succeeding).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Prevent an Alert Dialog Getting Closed by Back Button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7113591/how-to-prevent-an-alert-dialog-getting-closed-by-back-button)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you try

```
dialog.setCancelable(false);
```

It works in my case.

You are setting it to true

```
dialog.setCancelable(true);
```

Just change that

Comment: You know, I'm not that bad of a programmer, but sometimes I can make really stupid mistakes. Lol thanks! I will check your answer in 4 minutes(stackoverflow isn't letting me now)

Comment: Well since we're talking about "cancelable", what's the difference between "canceling" a popup and "dismissing" a popup?

Comment: Nevermind, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3125647/what-is-the-difference-between-a-dialog-being-dismissed-or-canceled-in-android

Comment: Cancel a dialog: You don't want to click on Ok or Cancel buttons, or Yes/No buttons of dialog. Just go back to your application.

Dismiss a dialog: You will click on Yes/No, action will beperformed according to your click and then dialog will be dismissed

Comment: Someone attempted to edit this answer with this alternative recommendation: "Or just override following method

`@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) {

    Log.d("back", "back button pressed");
}

return true; //to prevent this event from being propagated further.
}`"

Comment: Yeah...and why can you edit other people's posts!? That's just asking for trouble.